# Incorrect conversion of server timestamp to String

Tags: java, android, timestamp, simpledateformat

I'm trying to set date in ListView's Adapter from ArrayList of timestamps I got from server.

```
 Date date = new Date(news_date.get(position) * 1000);
 SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");
 ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.newsTvDate)).setText(sdf.format(date));
```

here is my log :

```
12-12 19:00:23.234: D/MyLog(13086):  news_date.get(position)=1385323200
12-12 19:00:23.254: D/MyLog(13086):  news_date.get(position)=1384718400
12-12 19:00:23.266: D/MyLog(13086):  news_date.get(position)=1384113600
12-12 19:00:23.275: D/MyLog(13086):  news_date.get(position)=1383508800
12-12 19:00:23.291: D/MyLog(13086):  news_date.get(position)=1383076800
12-12 19:00:55.426: D/MyLog(13086):  news_date.get(position)=1382904000
```

and as a result I see something like 02.01.70 , 26.12.69 etc
how do I fix it?

Comment: What does `news_date.get(position) * 1000` evaluate to?

Comment: And what is exactly your problem? What you want to achieve?

Comment: Just guessing: make sure `news_date.get(position)` does not evaluate to 0 and try to remove the `* 1000`.

Comment: Updated post with log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer overflow.

For example, `1385323200 * 1000` is too large to fit in a 32-bit integer. Promote one of the operands to 64-bit integer first: `1385323200 * 1000L`.

Comment: exactly ! Thank you very much. timestamp is integer so it's overflow when i multiply for java format

Answer (score -1):

you are probably getting wrong number in your news_date.get(position), try to find out why

edit:

by wrong i mean something close to 0 :P

Comment: Updated post with log .